# SQL Trigger Ideas

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to design a trigger that fires once I add a new record to the table[Transaction Table].
So here is the workflow:

User enters Services(Service Table)and Expenses(Expenses Table) in the system. Once they click button "process invoice" a row is created in the Transaction table.

Trigger should fire when the user Clicks the "Process Invoice"(which internally would be addition of row in the Transaction Table). Trigger should create a new entry (row) in the expense table that would be 2% of total of all entries in the services table.

I am new to Trigger writing.All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

> Trigger should fire when the user Clicks the "Process Invoice"

It would be better if when the user clicks "Process Invoice" you invoke a stored procedure that inserts both the Transaction and Expense rows.